# False warning of my past questions having not been well-received on UX

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message

Today, I went to ask a question on [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) and received the following warning:

[image: Visual Aid of Problem]

**Why am I getting this warning?**

My questions have been *well received* and I've deleted none of my questions on UX. I have never answered any questions on UX. I've provided a screenshot of my questions on UX:

[image: Second Visual Aid]
https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/81176/code-play

**Is it triggering this message because my last question was a duplicate? The question was still well received. Is this an error with UX?**

Comment: I had a [similar experience on superuser](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/9019/questions-have-not-been-well-received-warning-without-negative-or-deleted-ques). Not a single downvote, still got the warning. Very frustrating when they do not tell you what you should improve or where you failed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your last two questions ([1](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/91914/do-users-like-or-star), [2](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/91913/do-users-like-to-feel-more-special-than-the-elements-of-a-webpage)) were closed; this is what triggered the warning.

The threshold for this warning was based on an old, now-defunct system for question-bans. Given the warning no longer corresponds to anything you should be warned about, I've adjusted the parameters to eliminate it outside of extreme scenarios.

Comment: Would you please clarify which two questions? I've never had any question closed or deleted. Your link goes to the question that was marked as a duplicate. Does a duplicate count as a question being closed? Doesn't the question still count as being well received, even if it is marked as a duplicate?

Comment: @CodePlay: there are two links in Shog's answer, the second points to a question closed as "primarily opinion-based".